# Do have Windows Shortcuts anything like meta-parameters?

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcuts

Is it there special parameters that can be passed for targets of windows shortcuts ?

**Context parameters like**: the name of the current shortcut, its full path, shortcut folder name, or others ? Let's assume the meta-parameter $shortcutname was the shortcut name:

```
TARGET: "c:\folder1\subfolder\myprogram.exe" $shortcutname
```

**ONE USE CASE:**

Assume a program that has a parameter that identifies something inside its business, in this example lets say that the program needs a hostname and a lot of others parameters. Being the hostname the unique parameter that changes and all other else parameters is fixed. Consider the following:

```
myprogam -p1 blablabla -p2 123:5567 -p3 asbc.qwe -p4 "xxx" -hostname $hostname
```

Well, there are users that haven't skills to edit a shortcut, but they know how to change a file name in Windows Explorer. We could explain to the users, to just copy&paste the shortcut and change its name to the name that matches the hostname desired. Of course, if there was possible to pass the shortcut name as a meta-parameter to the shortcut's targets.

So, a workaround to do that could be making a .bat file that could deal with it. And so, using the same procedure, copy&paste, and adjust the name to match the hostname desired, but in some systems, the administrator's policies can be a barrier to the .bat scripts.

Need to say that the users already use the shortcuts, there are folders with dozens of them, but they are created by the support team.

Comment: Where would the input for such a parameter come from?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart From shortcut "interpreter", launcher, shell,... I don't know how it's called in Windows

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart : Pass to the program the name of the shortcut that launched it.

Comment: But what problem does this solve? (Why does the program need that information?)

Comment: Sorry, but there must be a language barrier. I simply don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart : Sorry, ins't an easy task to write comments in smartphones. I added an use case to the question. I hope that it can explains you what I was looking for.

Comment: If I understand what you want, Windows shortcut (`.lnk`) files are not what you would use, but rather a script. Regarding your comment "administrators' policies can be a barrier to the .bat scripts" - if you are referring to restricting execution of `cmd.exe`, that is a pointless restriction these days. It does not increase security in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly address a shortcut file there is no current shortcut.
You will have to use the wscript `createshortcut` method (also for existing shortcuts) See this script:

```
$ShortCutFile = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk"
$Wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$ShortCut = $wsh.CreateShortcut($ShortCutFile )
$ShortCut|Get-Member
$ShortCut|Format-List
```

Output:

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{f935dc23-1cf0-11d0-adb9-00c04fd58a0b}

Name             MemberType Definition
----             ---------- ----------
Load             Method     void Load (string)
Save             Method     void Save ()
Arguments        Property   string Arguments () {get} {set}
Description      Property   string Description () {get} {set}
FullName         Property   string FullName () {get}
Hotkey           Property   string Hotkey () {get} {set}
IconLocation     Property   string IconLocation () {get} {set}
RelativePath     Property   string RelativePath () {set}
TargetPath       Property   string TargetPath () {get} {set}
WindowStyle      Property   int WindowStyle () {get} {set}
WorkingDirectory Property   string WorkingDirectory () {get} {set}

FullName         : C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk
Arguments        :
Description      : Internetzugriff
Hotkey           :
IconLocation     : C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe,0
RelativePath     :
TargetPath       : C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
WindowStyle      : 1
WorkingDirectory : C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
```

You can modify the `$ShortCut` properties and then use the `.save` method.